# trouble creating ldap directory

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have a grails application and I'm unable to recreate an ldap folder structure that another project has. why is it that some directories are blue and others are brown?

[image: directory image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Why is it that some directories are blue and others are brown?
```

Intellij-idea have 4 types of directories color:

1. blue - source folder
2. brown - ordinary folder
3. green - test source folder
4. brown folder with a green dot - package

[image]

Ref# - [Intellij - Main Items](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html#d1013590e674)

**EDIT...........................................................................**

```
How to create source folder in Intellij-idea 13?
```

1. Create a folder eg. `ldap`
2. Right click on folder `ldap` > "Mark Directory As" (at bottom, third last option)
3. Click "Source Root"

that's all..,.

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: do you happen to know what it takes to make ldap a source folder? IntelliJ 13 doesn't seem to have an option for creating a source folder with right-click

Comment: I added the steps to create a source directory. Have a look..,.